# Flash - / routes does not load

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add the [flash](https://github.com/expressjs/flash) package to  my express project.

In my app.js  file I am loading flash via `app.use`:

```
const express = require("express")
const flash = require("flash")
const session = require("express-session")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "pug")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public"))) //public folder!
app.use(flash)
app.use(session({
    key: 'user_sid',
    secret: 'sessionSecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Thank you! Your feedback has been submitted.' });
    res.send('Hello World!')
})


const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080
const host = process.env.APP_HOST || "localhost"

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on " + host + ":" + port)
})
```

I am trying to show the flash in my view like the following:

```
for msg in flash
  a.alert(class='alert-' + message.type)
    p= message.message
```

However, my `/` routes does not load. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Appreciate your reply!

Comment: try `app.use(flash());` (not an expert on express, but in my working project it's setup that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the "Usage"-Section of https://github.com/expressjs/flash, the correct initialisation would be

```
app.use(require('flash')());
```

So you would have to add parentheses to line 10, that would be

```
app.use(flash());
```

(Since you already did the require-part, but still need to invoke, and not pass, flash)